# Produce an unexpected word

Tags: popularity-contest, underhanded

The goal is to write program that will produce a word **unexpectedly** (program doesn't look like it is going to produce a word).

Example (JavaScript):

```
alert(([0][1]+"").slice(4,8))
```

> alerts "fine" - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6W5R/3/).

Explanations:

> 1. `[0][1]` returns undefined, because there only one element in array `[0]`
>  2.  Adding empty string converts `undefined` to string "undefined"
>  3. `slice(4,8)` outputs fifth to eight characters of `undefined`

---

This is **underhanded popularity contest**.

Comment: I don't think this challenge is objectively measurable. How "unexpected" is "unexpected enough"?

Comment: I think this is more or less a dupe of the "Print an unexpected obscenity" question which has now been deleted so I can't find the link. That one was also an [tag:underhanded] about unexpectedly printing a word, with the constraint that it had to be an insult

Comment: I'm closing this question because, [by community consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8326/20469), underhanded challenges are no longer welcome on the site.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

## Python2.x

```
import re
try: re.compile("[")
except re.error, e: print e.message.split()[0]
```

[try it](https://ideone.com/Y7nLlY)

Comment: That was certainly unexpected.

Answer (score 102):

## CJam

```
"​​‌‌​​​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​​‌‌​‌‌‌‌​​​​‌​​​‌​‌‌‌​​​‌​​​​‌​​​‌‌​‌​​‌‌​​‌‌‌‌‌​‌​​​​​‌‌‌​​​‌‌​​​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‌​‌​‌‌‌​‌​‌​‌​‌‌​‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​​‌​‌​‌‌​​​​‌​‌​‌‌​​​​‌​​‌‌​​‌​‌‌​​​​‌​​‌‌‌​​​​​‌‌‌​​‌​‌​‌​‌​​‌‌‌‌​‌‌​​​​​​‌‌​‌​​​​‌​‌‌​​‌​​‌​‌​‌‌‌‌​​‌​‌‌​‌​‌​​​‌‌‌​‌​​​‌‌​​‌‌​​‌​‌‌​‌​​‌​​‌​‌‌‌​​‌‌​​‌‌​‌​‌‌​‌‌‌​​​‌​​​​‌​‌​​‌​​​​​​‌​‌‌​​‌‌​‌​​​‌​​‌​‌":iXf&YbBB*b:c
```

Prints *Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis*.

[Try it online.](http://tinyurl.com/nk2qges) (Permalink works in Chrome. You have to copy and paste the code in some browsers.)

To understand how it works, [click here](http://tinyurl.com/op6x7y2) to run this:

```
"​‎‏‌‎‌​​‎‍‌‍‌‏​‌‏‌​‏‌‏‍​‎‏‌‍​‏‏​‎‌‏‏​‍‍‏‏‏‎‍‎‏‌‌‎‍‎‏‏​‍‍‍‌‌‎‎‌‏​‎‏‏​‏‏‍‏‏‍​‌‍‌‏‏‎‍‏​‌‎‌‍‏‏‌‏​​‌​‍‏‌‍​‌‍​​‌‌‌‏​‎​​​‌‍​‏​‎‏​​​‎​‎‎‌​‏​​​‌‍‌‏‍‏‌​‌‎‏​​‌‏‎‎‎‎‌​‎​‏‏​‏‏‍‏‌​‍​‏‏​​‍‎‌‏‌‎‏‍‍‌‍‎‍‌​‍‌‎‏​‌‎‌‌‍‏‍‌​‌‍​‍‍​‏‌‏​‎‏‍​‎‎‎‍‍‌‌‏​‏​​‏‎‍‏‎‍‏​‎‏‏‍​‌‍‌​​​‍‌‌‎‎‍​‏‎‍‏‏‍‍​‍‍‌‌‏‏‍‏‌​‌‌​​‌‌​‌‍‍‎​‎‎‎‍​‌‎‌‏​‍‎​​‏​​‍‎​‏‌‍‍‎‌‌‏‏‌​‎‍‎‏‍‏‏‍‏‌‏‍‍‏‍‍‏‎‍​‎‌‏‎‍​​‎‎​‎‏‍‍‌‎‍‍‏‏‌‏‎‏​‎‍‍‍‎‍‌‎‎‌​‍‏​‌‏‏‍‎‎‏‏​‌‌‎‍‌‍‎‏‎‎‎‍‎‏‏‏‌‌‍‏‎‍‍‏‍‍​​‍‎‍‌‌‎‌‎‏‏‏‌​‎​‍‏‎‏‎‌‌‍‏‎‎‌‍​‎‏‍‍​‍‏‏‏‏‏‌‍‎‌​​​‍‏‏​‌​‎‌‏‌‎‎‍‎‍‎‏‌​‏‏‌​‏‎‍‍‏‌‎‍​‌‎‎‌​‍​‎‎‎‎‌‌‎​‎​​‏‌‍‍‌‎‍‍‏‎‎‏‍‎​‌‎‎‍‎‍​‎‎‏‎‌​‌‎‏‌‏‍‍‍‌‎‌‏‍​‍‍‍‍‍‌‌‎‍‏‎‎​​‎‎‎​‎​‏‍​​‏‎​​‍‌‌‍‌‍‎‍‍‏‏‏‎‌‏‍‏‎‎‌‍‌​‏‎‏‎‎‏‏‍‍‏‌‌‎‍‎‎‎‍‎‌​​‌‏‎‌​‏‍‍‍‌‍‏‌‌‍‌‌‎‍‌‏‍‎‍‌‏​‎‏‌​‎​‎‌‎​‌‍‌‏‎‌‌‌‌‎‍​‏​‌‌‎‌‌‏‍‎​‏‎‎‌‎‌‌‍‎‎‎‎‏‍‏‌‎‌‏‍‎​‏‍‍​​‍‎‏​‎‏​‏‎‌‍‍‏‍​‎‎‌‏‏‍‌‏‎‍‏‍‍‌‍​​‌‎‏‍‍‍​‏​‍​‏‏​‏‏‍‌‌‌‏‏‍‌‎‌‍‎‎‏​‏​‎‍‏‏‎‍​​‏​‏‎‏‌‌​​‏‍‍‍​‎​‏‌‎‍‌‏‌‏‎​‌‍‎​​‎‎​‏‌‌​‌​‏​‌​‎​‏​‎‏‌‎​‏​​​‍‌‏‏‏‌​‍‍‏​‍‌​​‎‏‍​‏‌​‏‍‌‏‏‏​‏‏‎​​​‌‎​‌​‏‎‌​‍‍‎​‏‎​‎‏‌‌‎‍‏‎‌​‎‏‌​‎‏‏‍‎‏​‌‍​‍​‍‎‎‌‎‎​‏​​‌‍‎‍‌‌‌​​‎‌‎‎‍​‏​‍‍‍​​​​‍‏‌​​​‍‎‌‌‌‍​‌‌‍‌‌‌‎‏‌‍‏‌‌‎‎‎‍‏‎​‍‌‍‏‍​‌‍‎‌‏‍‎​‎‏‎‍‎‏‎​​‏‍​‏‎​‎‏‍​​‏‎‍​‏‍‌‏‍‍‍‏‏‍‏‎​‎‌‏​‏‏‎‌‏​‍‏‎‎‌‌‏‏‍‎‏​‎‌​‌‌‎‌​‍‍​​‎‌​‍​​‏‍‎‏‎‌‍‍​‍‍‌‎​‌‏‏​​‏‌‏‍​‌‍‏‍‎‍​​‏​‏​‏‏‏‎​‎‌‏‏‍​‏‍‏‍‌‎‍‌‏‎‏‏‏‎‌‌​‏‌‍‏‌‌​‏‎‏‍​‌‏‏​‎‍‏‍‌‎‍‎‌‌‏‏‍‍‏‍‎‌‏‎‍‎‏‍‏‍‌​‌‏​‌‏‎‎‌‎‎‌‍‍‌‏‌‌‌‏‍‏‌‍‌​‏‍​‍‌​​‏‏​‌​‏‍‎‏‏‏‍‎‍‌‍‌‍‍‍‏‎‎‏‏‏‏​‌‏​‎​‏​‌‎‏‏‎‏​‍​​‍​​‍‌‏‍‏‌​​‎‍‏‌‏‏‍‏‎‌‎‍‏‍‎‍​‍‌‏‍‍‎‌‏‌​‎‎‍‎‏‎​‍​‍‍‏‏‎‍‏‎‌​‍‍‏‎​‍​‍‏‎‎‎‏‍​‏‌‌‌​‏‎‌​‎‌‍​‎‍‌‏‏‎‎​‏‌‌‍‏‏‎​‍‌​​‎‍‏‎‌‏‎‏‌‌‌​‍‍‌‍‏​‌‎‌​‏‌​​‎‍‏‌‍​‍‎​​‎​​​‌​​​​‎‎​‌‎‎‎​‎‍‏‍‍‎‏‌‌‌‍‎​​‏‎‎‍‍‍‍‏‎‌‍​​​‍‍‍‎​‎‏‌‎‏​‍‌‍‍‍‏‌​‌‌​‎​‏​‍​‍‏‏‎‎‍‎‍‌​‏‎‌​‏‏​‎​‌‎​​​​‎‏‍‌​​‎​‌‎​‏‌‌‍‍‌‎‎​‎‎‍‌​‎‍​​‍‎‍‎‌‌‍‌‌‌‌‌‏‎‏​‌‎‏‎‌‏‌‏‍‍‎‌‌‎‎‌‍​‌​​‏‍‌‎‏‍​‎‍‍‍‎‍‌‎‎​‌​‏‎‏‏‏‏‏‎‎‍‌​‏‍‎‏‎‏‍‎‌‌‌‍‌​‎‌​‌‏‎‎‎​‌​‌‎‏‏‏‌‎‌‍​‌‏‏‏‎‎‍‏‏‎‍‎‌‎‏‌‎‎‍​‌‌‌‍‏‍‏​‍‎​‍‎​‏‌‍‏​‌‍‎‏‎‎‏‌‎‌‏​‎​‍‌‍‌‎‏​‌‍‌​‏‎​​‏‏‎​​​​‍​‎‍​‏‌​‍‌‌‌​‏‏‏‏‍‍‎‍‌‌‌‍‎‎‍‏​‎‍‏‌‍‎‏‏‍‍​​‌‎​‎‌​‎‏‍‌‌‏‌‏‏‍‍​‌‎‎‏‌‍‎​‌‏‍‍‎‌‌‏‎‍​‎​‎‌‎‏​​‍​‎‌‍‍‍‏‏‌‌‏‌‌​​‍‏‌‍​‏‌‍‏‎​‏‏‏‌‍‏‌‌‎‏‍​‎​‏​‏‎‌‏‏​‌‏​‍‏‍​‎‎​‌​‎‎‎‌​‍​‍​‌‎‌‌​‍​​‏‎‏‏‎‏‏​‎‎‌‍‏‏​​​‍‌‍​‎‏‏‏‏​‏‎‏‏‌​‌‎‎​​‎‎‏​​‏‍‎‎‎‏‌‎‍‎‎‌​‌‌‌‎‌‍‎‎‍‌‍‍‌‌​‎‏‌‏‌‎​‌‎‍‍​‏‎​‏‌​​‎‎​‌​‌‌‌‏‍‍‏‎‌‏‏‏‎‎‎‍‌​‏​​‏‌‎‌‎‏‌‍‍‎‍‌‍‍‍​‍​‎‍‌‌​‍‍‏‌‌‍‏‏‍‏​‎‎‍‍‎‎‍‏​‍‎‌​‍‌‎‏‍​‏‌‍‍‎‏​​‏​‍‌​‍‍‎‏‍‎‍​​‎‌‍‎‎​‏‍‌​‌‏‏‎‌‏​‎‏‏​‎​‌‌‍‍‍‏​‌​​‌‎‍‏‎‍‌‌‏‌‌‎‌‌‍‏‍‍‏​‌‌‎‏‌‍‌‎‌‍‎​​‎​‎‍‏‌‌​​‏‎​​‏‍‏‍‏‏​‎‍‎‏‏‌​‌​‍‌‌‏‎​‎‍‍​​​​‏‍‏‏‍‍":i5f%5b5I*b' f+~
```

#### I still don't get it!

- > The first code block is actually 970 bytes long, since there are 318 zero-width characters (U+200B and 0+200C) between the two double quotes. Even with a monospaced font, these characters are completely invisible.
- > `X`, `Y` and `B` are variables initialized to 1, 2 and 11.
- > `:iXf&` casts each character to an integer (8203 or 8204) and computes the parity. This way, U+200B becomes 1 and U+200C becomes 0.
- > `Yb` converts the array of integers from above to an integer by considering it a base 2  number.
- > `BB*b` converts that integer into an array of its digits as a base 121 number.
- > The sad smiley `:c` casts each digit to its corresponding ASCII character.
- > The second code block is actually 6543 bytes long. It follows the same idea, but it uses the characters U+200B to U+200F, base 5 numbers and string evaluation.

Comment: Oh, you sneaky rascal :)

Comment: Very very tricky. +1

Answer (score 42):

## Python

I don't expect any upvote (but pwease don't downvote this either - unless the net votes are above 0!), because of course I claim *NO MERIT WHATSOEVER* on this answer, but in my opinion, the award would go hands down to **Tim Peters** for this Python code...

```
import this
```

(If you've never heard about it, [try it here](https://ideone.com/aL3cl6) :) )

Comment: Em... Explain, please. ))

Comment: @nicael this is "The Zen of Python", or PEP20 - it's a series of affirmations about how Python scripts should be implemented, and it has been hard-coded into Python as module `this`... as an easter egg, if you wish :)

Answer (score 32):

Ok - here'we go:

**Javascript:**

```
new Function("‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍".split("‌").map(function(v){return String.fromCharCode(v.length)}).join(''))();
```

Evaluate it in your console...

> It can't be that easy. Try to find it yourself.

Comment: Certainly +1. Explain please! ))

Comment: I found it! https://whiskers75.co.uk/assets/OHMYGODWHATTHE.png

Comment: +1 For those wondering how this works, paste the code into this tool: http://mothereff.in/js-escapes

Comment: You can shorten this by replacing `new Function(...)();` with `eval(...);`

Comment: Yes, but this is not a code golf and I think `new Function(...)();` looks way more confusing as it is hiding the eval :)

Comment: This kills my shell. http://i.imgur.com/i7ElDry.png

Answer (score 27):

## C - ioccc feeling

```
#define\
    __(a,b) b##a
    __(in(O){,ma)
    __(at*f=&O;,flo)
    #define\
    _ __(ntf("%f",*f);,pri)
    __(ng,lo)__(ng $;O=, lo)
        __(NE__;$=,__LI)
        O*4*2699*14449
        *__(1ll,1765069);O=~--O;_-_-
        _-_-_-_-_-_-__(ts(&$);},pu)
```

**output (using gcc 4.7.2):**

> -nan-nan-nan-nan-nan-nan-nan-nan BATMAN

## C - WinApi

leave it to the professionals

```
#include <Windows.h>

CONST CCHAR *ParseStringOutputHandler(HANDLE hOut)
{
    /*
    * Prototype for SEH support function.
    */
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO SBInfo;
    COORD crdSBInfoCoord;
    COORD crdMaxWinSize;
    COORD crdSize;
    WORD wMagicNum = 0x40;
    WORD wAttr = 0x14;
    INT8 i;
    static CCHAR szParseArray[9];
    /*
    *       This file contains the definitions and prototypes for the compiler-
    *       dependent intrinsics, support functions and keywords which implement
    *       the structured exception handling extensions.
    */
    crdSBInfoCoord.X = _WIN32_WINNT_NT4 >> 8;
    crdSBInfoCoord.Y = SUBVERSION_MASK / 28;
    crdMaxWinSize.X = EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER | 0x2;
    crdMaxWinSize.Y = (_WIN32_IE>>010) + 3;
    crdSize.X = _WIN32_IE_IE20 >> 0x8;
    crdSize.Y = 0x15;
    SBInfo.dwCursorPosition = crdSBInfoCoord;
    SBInfo.dwMaximumWindowSize = crdMaxWinSize;
    SBInfo.dwSize = crdSize;
    SBInfo.wAttributes = wAttr;
    /*
    * Currently, all MS C compilers for Win32 platforms default to 8 byte
    * alignment.
    */
    for (i = 1; i <= 8; ++i){
        switch (i){
        case STRICT:         szParseArray[i-1] = SBInfo.dwCursorPosition.X;     break;
        case DM_COPY:        szParseArray[i-1] = SBInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y;     break;
        case DC_PAPERSIZE:   szParseArray[i-1] = SBInfo.dwMaximumWindowSize.X;  break;
        case _CRT_PACKING/2: szParseArray[i-1] = SBInfo.dwMaximumWindowSize.Y;  break;
        case 0x5:            szParseArray[i-1] = SBInfo.dwSize.X;               break;
        case DC_BINS:        szParseArray[i-1] = SBInfo.dwSize.Y;               break;
        case (_WIN32_WINNT>>8)|(_WIN32_WINNT&1):
        case 010:            szParseArray[i-1] = SBInfo.wAttributes;
        }
        szParseArray[i-1] |= wMagicNum;
        if (i > 7){
            szParseArray[sizeof(szParseArray)-1] |= wMagicNum;
        }
    }
    szParseArray[8] = NULL; // set WINVER based on _WIN32_WINNT
    return szParseArray;
}
```

**output:**

> DICKBUTT

Comment: i feel offended :'(

Answer (score 22):

### CJam

This is my first practice with **CJam**:

```
77c79c_78c7(8+6*3+c"K"["MICHAEL" "JACKSON"]:Ls4=Ls6=@'R'E\
```

I'm sure I could do it better with more practice but it was fun.

It prints out

> MOONWALKER

You can check it out [here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/).

Comment: Yep. Good answer.

Answer (score 19):

## C

*Works only on a little-endian machine*

How to make a simple multiplication ?

```c
int main(void) {
    //this is an easy multiplication example
    int a = 37897 * 210;

    //print the result
    printf("%s",&a);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs `boy`

> 37897*210 = 7958370 (0x796f62)
>  `boy` ASCII representation is 62-6f-79 (0x796f62 on little-endian)
>  printf with `%s` print the string, not the integer.

[**>> Try it here**](http://ideone.com/IskGA8)

Comment: try it with `uint64_t a = 30980630101 << 4`

Comment: @mebob The pen is mightier.

Answer (score 18):

## Javascript

**Round 2:**

**Improved Solution:**

```
try{Joe}catch(е){alert(е.message.replace(/de?/g,''))}
```

*53 characters*

**Old Solution:** Prints the same but in more short `char` length:

```
try{Joe}catch(е){console.log(е.message.replace(/de|d/g,''))}
```

*60 characters*

**Round 1:**

*I am going to Joe's place, he is sick, even computer says that:*

```
try {
    x = Joe;
} catch (err) {
    msg = err.message.split(" ");
    console.log(msg[0] + " " + msg[1] + " " + msg[2] + " " + msg[3].substring(2, 6));
}
```

*162 characters.*

```
try{x=Joe}catch(e){m=e.message.split(" ");console.log(m[0]+" "+m[1]+" "+m[2]+" "+m[3].substring(2,6))};
```

*103 characters.*

*"Joe is not fine"*

Comment: Ahahahahaha: ReferenceError: Joe is not de_fine_d -> Joe is not fine

Comment: Here's a shorter version (60 chars):
`try{Joe}catch(е){console.log(е.message.replace(/de|d/g,''))}`

Comment: @ДамянСтанчев can I use that as my answer please? :P

Comment: Sure, not a problem :)

Comment: If you're going for brevity: `try{Joe}catch(е){alert(е.message.replace(/de?/g,''))}`

Comment: I **am** fine, thank you very much!

Comment: @Joe , I'm glad you are fine. :)

Answer (score 14):

## dc

`dc` can be used with pretty obscure expressions. Here is an example, nearly asking you a question! (second line):

```
dc -e '[<!][P[ ]P]sr[|]30 4+[p]5[ ]500d+300dZ73 16d6-r[PnPnPnPP]sa[sz-=r2;h*7+++[know ]lax]sb
    vv:ha7 d0 [you] sp[eak?]                                                             lbx'
```

> Output: `I know 1337 5p34|<!`

Edit: splitting original answer into three different ones (`bash` and haskell proposals in separate posts)

Comment: You can split this into multiple answers if you'd like.

Comment: You *should* split these into multiple answers, that way people can vote on each individually.

Comment: Ok, I have split my original post. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 14):

## C, C++

Here's an oldie that could easily be adapted to other programming languages:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0x6F56DF77;
    printf("%8X", (i << 1) + 1);
}
```

> The trick is using the numbers >9 in hexadecimal (or higher) number systems. This one print's `DEADBEEF`, but there can be many [variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak). AFAIK Mac OS used to mark released memory in certain debug builds as dead beef.

[Try it!](http://ideone.com/uNaoPG)

Comment: You should avoid `void main`, some compilers such as `clang` error on it. `int main` without actually returning won't cause an error, though.

Comment: `void main` to hell.

Comment: void main is a old standard for DOS, I think (got a book about Turbo C++...).

Answer (score 13):

### Common Lisp

No attempts to hide *how* this one works.

```
(let ((*print-base* 36))
  (print #x1A92721254086478787CE5D7))
```

> SPANISHINQUISITION

Comment: +1. Did not expect.

Comment: @mniip Nobody does...

Answer (score 12):

## sed

Of course with `sed` one is waiting for a string output. But if you do not already know this one, I think it can be considered as… unexpected:

```
sed 's/ //g;s/h.*yo//;s/od.*//;y/euHodityn,/ -aegmoptt/;s/ //;e'
    <<< 'Hey, have you done it today?'
```

I can't write the answer correctly in a “spoiler” block, so you'll have to try it yourself :)

(Hint: works best on Debian/Ubuntu. Don't loose your time on Mac.)

**Edit:** I discovered that I *could* use code in spoiler blocks, so output is now hidden below.

> ```
>          (__)
>          (oo)
>    /------/
>   / |    ||
>  *  /---/\
>     ~~   ~~
> ...."Have you mooed today?"...
> ```

Comment: `sh: apt-get: command not found` Were you trying to install something on my computer?

Comment: @undergroundmonorail: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92185/whats-the-story-behind-super-cow-powers

Comment: *Don't loose your time on Mac.* Or on the dozens of (debatably superior) non-Debian based OSes...

Answer (score 10):

## CJam

```
PT/
```

Try it at http://cjam.aditsu.net/

Also, for fun:

```
"HAL":)
```

Answer (score 8):

## PowerShell

Can it be multiple words? If so, allow this to blow your freakin' mind.

```
function recurse() {
    $r = 72,29,7,0,3,-79,87,-8,3,-6,-8  
    $s = ""
    $t = {
        $a,$b = $r
        $d+=$args[0]+$a
        $s+=[char]$d
        if ($b -ne $null) {
            return recurse $d $b $s
        }
        return $s
    }
    function recurse() {
        $r = $args[1]
        $s = $args[2]
        . $t
    }
    . $t
}
recurse 0
```

> Returns "Hello world" in a very complicated way

Comment: Of course, it can.

Answer (score 8):

## **Ruby**

```
def handle(switch)
  case switch
  when 'a',
    print(switch << 'a')
  when 'n',
    print(switch.sub!('b','n'))
  when 'q',
    print(switch.gsub('b','q'))
  when 'b',
    nil
  else
    print('s!')
  end
end

handle('b')
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/h9VJVK)

Comment: bananas! Yep, but *what if* I don't like bananas? Anyway, +1, good example (actually I like bananas).

Comment: If you don't like bananas, simply pass 'a' instead of 'b' and then yes, we have no bananas.

Answer (score 7):

## Perl

```perl
print pack qq;
\1108;
,hex for qw;
2e5d66e 4b88fad 4560770 3aedf79;
```

Prints a friendly message for a special day!

> Outputs `Happy Birthday!!` (Was given to a programmer friend who hates Perl.)
>
> The white space and semicolon as the delimiting characters are meant to deceive.
>
> **qq;\1108;** (equivalent to "H8")
>  
>  The semicolons are the delimiters for the double quote method. \110 is the octal code for H, followed by a plain 8, giving us the packing code "H8", meaning 8 hex digits
>
> **hex**
>  
>  Converts a hex string to an integer. No parameter means it runs on $_ (default variable)
>
> **for qw;2e5d66e 4b88fad 4560770 3aedf79;**
>  
>  The semicolons are the delimiters for the quoted list method. `for` indicates to run the entire block on the left once per each hex string.
>
> "Unobfuscated", the script is:
>  
> `print pack("H8", hex($_)) for (2e5d66e 4b88fad 4560770 3aedf79);`
>
> Each of those hex values, when de-hexed into an 8 digit number, and then packed into a 4 characters, will print 4 of the letters of **Happy Birthday!!**

[**Run it here**](http://ideone.com/rCkc5b)

Answer (score 7):

*The goal is to write program that will produce a word unexpected*

I didn't read past that. I have a serious issue with reading long passages (and error messages).

I decided to create a simple program that alerts "5". Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    function logError(e) {
        // I have a serious issue with reading long error messages
        // I'll just print the first word of the error and figure out what it means
         console.log(e.message.split(" ")[0]);
    }
    // Useful assert method for debugging
    function assert(value, message) {
        if (value === false) {
            throw new Error(message);
        }
    }

    // Sets a varaible "a" to 5 and alerts it
    try {
        // Try it the old fashioned way
        a = 5;
        alert(a);
    } catch (e) {
        logError(e);

        // In some legacy browsers, that might now work
        // because alert requires a string
        try {
            // create objA which has a method "word", which always returns a word, or a string
            var objA = {
                word: function () {
                    return new String(5);
                }
            };
            // Make sure it is a string
            assert(typeof objA.word() === "string", "word didn't return a string");
            alert(objA.word());
        } catch (e) {
            logError(e);
            // Some browsers, such as chrome, just won't work
            // It's time to be evil and force them to work!
            try {
                eval("a = 5" +
                    "alert(a)");
            } catch (e) {
                logError(e);
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Tested in the google chrome console.
It produces (literally) *a word unexpected*.

http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/Af4sH/
(For the jsfiddle, you must open your console, there won't be any html output)

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript

> alerts "hello"

```
var $$ = String.fromCharCode;this[(+{}+[])[-~[]]+(![]+[])[-~-~[]]+([][+[]]+[])[-~-~-~[]]+(!![]+[])[-~[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]($$((((((+!+[])+(-~+[]))+((!+![])^((+!+[])+(-~+[]))))*(((+!+[])+(-~+[]))+((!+![])^((+!+[])+(-~+[]))))*(((+!+[])+(-~+[]))*((+!+[])+(-~+[])))))+(((+!+[])+(-~+[]))*((+!+[])+(-~+[]))))+$$((((((+!+[])+(-~+[]))+((!+![])^((+!+[])+(-~+[]))))*(((+!+[])+(-~+[]))+((!+![])^((+!+[])+(-~+[]))))*(((+!+[])+(-~+[]))*((+!+[])+(-~+[])))))+(-~+[]))+$$((((((+!+[])+(-~+[]))+((!+![])^((+!+[])+(-~+[]))))*(((+!+[])+(-~+[]))+((!+![])^((+!+[])+(-~+[]))))*(((+!+[])+(-~+[]))*((+!+[])+(-~+[])))))+(((((+!+[])+(-~+[]))*((+!+[])+(-~+[])))*((+!+[])+(-~+[])))))+$$((((((+!+[])+(-~+[]))+((!+![])^((+!+[])+(-~+[]))))*(((+!+[])+(-~+[]))+((!+![])^((+!+[])+(-~+[]))))*(((+!+[])+(-~+[]))*((+!+[])+(-~+[])))))+(((((+!+[])+(-~+[]))*((+!+[])+(-~+[])))*((+!+[])+(-~+[])))))+$$(((((((+!+[])+(-~+[]))+((!+![])^((+!+[])+(-~+[]))))*(((+!+[])+(-~+[]))+((!+![])^((+!+[])+(-~+[]))))*(((+!+[])+(-~+[]))*((+!+[])+(-~+[])))))+(((((+!+[])+(-~+[]))*((+!+[])+(-~+[])))*((+!+[])+(-~+[])))))+(((!+![])^((+!+[])+(-~+[]))))));
```

*caveat: one variable declaration.(no time for changing `String.fromCharCode` to symbols)*

[more readable code](http://pastie.org/private/ccpgdwddgstzwglkonktuw) (solution is derived from this code (it's mine BTW))

#### Ref:

1. http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?24,33349,33405
2. http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html (inspired for accessing `alert` from symbols)

Comment: This might run in Lisp, and Brainfuck as well.

Comment: @AnubianNoob I tried it in brainfuck, it goes to an infinite loop. Also i did in Lisp, throws syntax error.

Comment: It would have been pretty funny if it _did_ work ;)

Comment: This one isn't code-golf, no need to make it compact (and unreadable) or to count characters.

Comment: @Alejandro the code being unreadable makes it unexpected to give any output. BTW, I have removed the reference to number of characters

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby

```
display(STDOUT) unless case class Do
self
end when method(:print).to_proc
end
```

I've used this trick in an earlier underhanded contest, but I thought I'd dress up the output a bit differently.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/QpiePQ)

First person to explain where the word

> Domain

comes from wins a no-prize.

Comment: The last part of the word is easy. The display method of the ruby main class is writing itself to STDOUT. It's printed second, because everything after unless needs to be evaluated first to decide whether to execute the code before it. After the case statement returns nil, it is printed. The first part of the word is the tricky part. The case statement is comparing the Do class to main's print method as a proc. The when clause compares using ===, and the Proc === method is defined to invoke its code block with the other object as the parameter so it calls print with Do as the parameter.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, 10 characters

`alert(1/0)`

Test it on http://jsfiddle.net/cC52Z/!

### Output

> Infinity

### Explanation

> Instead of disallowing division by zero, JavaScript makes it always return Infinity (division of a negative by zero produces -Infinity).

Comment: I love it )) Good answer.

Comment: I expected that.

Comment: Not unexpected...

Answer (score 5):

### Emacs Lisp for version 22.1.1 (that comes on osx)

Run this right on the command line

`emacs -q --batch --eval "(progn (execute-kbd-macro \"\C-[xinfo\C-m\C-[xfun\C-i\C-m\C-u49\C-n\") (search-forward (string(+ ? ? (*)? )(+(/ ? (+(*)(*)(*))) ? ? ? (*(+(*)(*))(+(*)(*))))))(print (buffer-substring-no-properties (+(*)(*)(*)(point)) (progn (forward-word(*)) (point)))))"`

Output: **"woman"**

[image: demo]

Answer (score 5):

### Python

Inspired by @Roberto's answer.

```
try: exec('from __future__ import braces')
except Exception as e: print(e.msg)
```

> Another Python easter egg; it prints: `not a chance`

Answer (score 5):

### TI-BASIC

```
:
```

(Either type the colon on an empty screen, or make an empty program or one containing just colons.)

Prints "Done"

Answer (score 5):

## [Homespring](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Homespring)

<sup><sup>(Empty program)</sup></sup>

#### Output

> In Homespring, the null program is not a quine.

#### Why?

> Homespring prints this message when interpreting a empty program to prevent cheating at [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) code golf challenges

Answer (score 4):

## GolfScript

```ruby
0:b;"#{STDIN.inspect}"${b{..}{.}if 78={6-.1:b;}{}if;}%
```

Outputs:

```
HOST
```

[Try it out here.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MDpiOyIje1NURElOLmluc3BlY3R9IiR7YnsufXt9aWYgNzg9ezsnSCcxOmI7fXt9aWZ9JQ==)

How it works:

> `"#{STDIN.inspect}"` returns `"#<IO:<STDIN>>"`. `$` sorts it into `"#:<<>>DIINOST"`. The rest of the program loops through the string, dropping chars until it finds an `N`. Then, it changes the `N` to a `H` and keeps the rest of the chars.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl

```
#!perl
eval('(*16,z<=:3??0<x06161xBBQ$8t'^((
'0'x27)^((((((('h'x6).'A'.'b'x5).'a'.
'h'x2).'A'.'h'x5).'A'.'H'x3).'f'x2))))
```

> **Output:** Mohammad Anini 3:)

Comment: If you use the `>!` command, you can hide what this code does until a mouse scrolls over the text.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia

```
(repr(typeof(""))*repr(typeof(' '))*repr(typeof(1//1)))[6:7:27]
```

Another option:

```
print(print())
```

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL

```
declare @S char(3)  -- Declare a string variable that holds three characters
set @S = 1000       -- Implicitly convert the value 1000 to string
select ascii(@S)    -- Get the ASCII code value of the leftmost character
```

Outputs

> The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18418)

Comment: Maybe I can't create fiddle, could you create it?

Comment: @nicael Does the link not work for you?

Comment: But it outputs column_0 42.

Comment: Yes it does. Don't kill the messenger but 42 **is** the answer to the ultimate question.

Comment: @nicael Haven't you ever tried [calculating that?](http://google.com/search?q=the+answer+to+the+ultimate+question+of+life+the+universe+and+everything)

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur I see xD

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript

```
for (var i in this) {
  if(parseInt(i[0]+i[2],16)==174) {
    this[i](i[0]+i[1]+i[2]);
    break;
  }
}
```

Not the cleverest. But, I sure do like what it has to say!

[Tested in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/Geq3Z/).

Comment: Nice, but too short.

Comment: Thanks ... But, too short? ... What's the requirement?

Comment: Simply it is popularity contest.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash

```
<<< echo echo echo
```

or

```
`echo echo echo`
```

> Both commands output `echo`, of course.

Comment: Also available in recursive version with the `$()` syntax: `$(echo $(echo echo $($(echo echo) echo)))`, same output…

Comment: You got me at first.

Answer (score 3):

## Java

This code is a bit long, outputs word:

> SEVERE

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Text
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        makeSureWeCantOutputText();
        unexpected();
    }

    private static void unexpected()
    {
        try
        {
            //this does nothing
            long x = 1;
            for( int i = 1; i / i == 1; i++ )
            {
                x++;
            }
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            Logger.getLogger( Text.class.getName()).log( Level.SEVERE, "");
        }
    }

    private static void makeSureWeCantOutputText()
    {
        try
        {
            //OutputStream class that outputs to nowhere
            PrintStream stream = new PrintStream( new OutputStream()
            {

                @Override
                public void write( int b ) throws IOException
                {
                }

            } );

            //replace System.out field with OutputStream that does nothing
            Field field = System.class.getDeclaredField( "out" );
            field.setAccessible( true );

            Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField( "modifiers" );
            modifiersField.setAccessible( true );
            modifiersField.setInt( field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL );

            field.set( null, stream );
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            //we don't want to outpout anything if it fails
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

> When exception is thrown we use Logger. Logger with Level.SEVERE Logger uses System.err instead of System.out. i / i throws exception when i reaches 0 (it starts from 1 and increases, then integer overflows to Integer.MIN_VALUE and is increased to 0).

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
a = self.methods.map{|x|x.to_s}
b = a.count
p a[b/2-8]+a[b-6]
```

Outputs:

```
"freeze!"
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby

Bit late to the party, but couldn't help but notice that no-one had done something like this:

```
puts 65791925216734442002988169043447582627179158156970580.to_s(36)
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/ju3GBc)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript

```
function rgbToHex(rgb) {
  var r = rgb[0].toString(16);
  var g = rgb[1].toString(16);
  var b = rgb[2].toString(16);
  return '#' + r + g + b;
}

alert(rgbToHex([176,0,11]));
```

Comment: The hex converter doesn't properly zero pad and yes it alerts #b00b.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript

Test it on your browser's console

```
x = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 2 : 0;
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('question-hyperlink')[0].text.substr(13 - x,13 + x))
```

Comment: Yep, good. Wonderful. No need to add explanation )) However if word is expected, I expect it. Anyway, +1.

Answer (score 2):

## J

This is what happens if you're bored.

```
'Nqbs a `u{c vac'({&a.@-@(t@[-+:@t=:a.&i.@]))'Kill a good man'
```

Output:

> `Have a nice day`.

Why?

> It calculates `-y - x - x` where `x` is the left string and `y`is the right string.

Comment: And it for sure isn't taking home the cleverness award, but I like it.

Answer (score 2):

**IBM Enterprise COBOL**

```
   ID DIVISION. 
   PROGRAM-ID. ERRMSG. 
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION. 
   DATA DIVISION. 
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  A PIC 9 VALUE ZERO. 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
       ADD 1 TO A 
       GOBACK 
       .
```

Here's a short program. It obviously does nothing but add one to the field A.

However, toss it into the compiler, and... http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21156178

> You can generate a complete listing of compiler diagnostic messages with their >message numbers, severities, and text by compiling
>   a program that has program-name ERRMSG.
>
> You can code just the PROGRAM-ID paragraph, as shown below, and omit the rest >of the program.

The key is to have `errmsg` as the `PROGRAM-ID`. No other code is required. The code in my example is just to convince that it is a real program which produces no output.

This is the example IBM show in the link:

```
Identification Division.
Program-ID. ErrMsg.
```

Indeed, this is enough:

```
Program-ID. ErrMsg.
```

Or this:

```
Program-ID. ErrMsg.
The quick brown fox jumped over the 
lazy dog, or any other text you like.
```

This is an example of the output: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21156178&aid=1

When the compiler gets to errmsg. (note the full-stop/period, which doesn't have to be immediately after errmsg, but must exist after it somewhere in the source) it knows what is needed, reads to the end of the source and then produces the listing, including the description of the format and information contained in the error messages, and all the messages themselves.

As a curiosity, you can try this:

```
Program-ID. ErrMsg
```

This time no full-stop/period is encountered before the end of the source is reached, and a (very) minor compiler bug is revealed, as the compiler continues reading, and abends (ends abnormally, crashes) with an S001 Reason Code 5 and

```
IEC020I GET ISSUED AFTER END-OF-FILE
```

No IBM Mainframe COBOL has ever separately documented its error messages in an actual manual.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica

```
ToString[#&@;;]~StringTake~{16,20}
```

Prints "Dummy". But I seriously do not understand why `#&@;;` does..what it does.

Comment: Funny note: None of the letters `Dumy` appear in the code.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript - 19 chars

This one is inspired by Gary Bernadt's 'wat' talk: [Video Link](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

```
([]+{}).substr(1,6)
```

Unexpected because `Array []` + `Object {}` should not output an Object.

> "object"

Another solution suggested by [bebe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/23057/bebe)

```
(0+{}).slice(2,8)
```

> "object"

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica

```
SeedRandom[377]; FromCharacterCode@RandomInteger[{98, 123}, 5]
```

> outputs `proof`

```
BaseForm[272580165883129, 29]
```

> outputs `impossible`

You can try the second one online in [Mathics](http://www.mathics.net/).  Type in the code and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  The first one is implementation specific, thus it won't work in Mathics, but it does work in *all* recent versions of Mathematica.

Comment: outputs "impossible[base 29]", the 29 is beneath impossible. Why is it impossible?

Comment: @MegaMan I don't understand your question

Answer (score 1):

## Perl

```
open IN, "<".$0;
while (<IN>) {
        chomp;
        (m/(^|[^\)])w.i.e/ && (s/^.(.).(.)(.).*/$1$3$2$2/ && print $_)) || m/(^|[^\)])...se/ && (s/^..(.).*/$1/ && print $_."\n");
}
close IN;
```

> Opens it's own script file and prints out some of the characters.

Answer (score 1):

### C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned long long ULL;
#define C(x) cout<<(ULL)(x)<<endl
int main ()
{
    ULL b=UINT_MAX;
    ULL d=LLONG_MAX;

    ULL f=(ULL)(d/b);
    size_t n = (log(f)/log(10))+1;
    char *w=new char[n];
    char x;
    for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x = (char)((f%10)+'@');
        f=(ULL)(f/10);
        w[n-i-1]=((n-i)<4)?x:0;
    }
    cout<<w<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces the word "BAD".

Answer (score 1):

## [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/)

```
>~~ufp~<.[-.<]
```

> outputs "poet"

Comment: Everything what bf and its derivates do is unexcepted...

Answer (score 1):

### Burlesque

```
blsq ) 4593109656 128B!
"hello"
blsq ) vvSh29.-4.+
"size"
```

**Explanation**

`128B!` is just base 128.

`vvSh29.-4.+` produces an error, converts the error to a string and then slices.

Answer (score 1):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/newmouse/blob/master/mouse.c)

```
' '  + 20 + b + a + !'
' '  + 13 + i + z + !'
' '  + 4  + i + z + !'
' '  + 23 + i + z + !'
' '  + 15 + i + z + !'
' '  + 4  + i + z + !'
' '  + 2  + i + z + !'
' '  + 19 + i + z + !'
' '  + 4  + i + z + !'
' '  + 3  + i + z + !'
'  '   +  s  -  !'
'  '   +  n n + n n + + c + -  !'

$
```

Output:

> `Unexpected.`

Explanation:

> uses ascii charcodes. the letters refer to addresses, which are integers in the range `0-25`.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 59 or 31 chars

Does it have to be a real word? If not, this will work:

```
echo preg_replace('/[0-9]+/',"",substr(md5(time()),0,25));
```

or even this if numbers are okay:

```
echo substr(md5(time()),0,25);
```

Set a range

```
echo substr(md5(time()),0,rand(1,50));
```

Comment: I am so stupid. I mean "knife", not "nife". As I can not produce "knife", I edited my example to produce "fine". (Such word exists, isn't it? :) )

Comment: I clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell

Classic:

```
let 1+1="Hello World!" in 1 + 1
```

> Outputs `Hello World!`. No kidding.

Comment: Should be a word.