# Help me get a date for Homecoming

Tags: popularity-contest

My school has its Homecoming dance next week, and there's someone in mind I want to ask. But I don't want to ask her the normal way. I want to send her a program that prints "Rachel, will you go to Homecoming with me?" However, if I just send her `print"Rachel, will you go to Homecoming with me?"`, it'll be way too obvious. That's where CG.SE comes in.

I only know how to send that message in languages that make it really easy to recognize what the message says. I need some help obfuscating the message.

Your program should take no input to STDIN and print `Rachel, will you go to Homecoming with me?` to STDOUT.

This is [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), meaning that I will use the code with the most upvotes. Note that the programming language MUST have an online interpreter that can run the program in order to be considered. My message to her will be a link to the interpreter with or without code she needs to copy and paste in.

Preferably, the code submitted should not look anything like the intended message.

If she says yes, I will also make a programming challenge in your honor.

Thank you very much for helping.

---

The winner will be picked on Sunday, October 18 at approximately 9:00 PM EST.

Comment: If you're actually asking somekne to a dance, tbh it sounds really lame if she asks, "how long did it take you to make this" and you respond "I challenged the internet to code me this"

Comment: @ThomasKwa This is a backup if I give up on my Brainfuck proposal. There's no way for me to get around the lameness, I'm afraid.

Comment: Now if there were a Fishing interpreter in a language I know how to use, then I'd be good to go, but alas, there isn't.

Comment: "The winner will be the program that it think looks the most obfuscated." That's not an objective winning criterion.

Comment: Maybe "The fewest repeated characters with no literals" would be better?

Comment: Is the girl into computer science and programming? If not, she'll probably think this is lame. Honestly, the best way to ask someone to (a) dance is just to ask her in person... Especially for homecoming. Many people prefer or pre-arrange to go in a group of friends. It's better not to do a fancy setup just to ask someone.

Comment: @AlexA. I have accepted an edit that fixes the non-objective winning criterion.

Comment: yup was just about to suggest popularity contest. Good luck!

Comment: So when will it be reopened?

Comment: @ppperry Hopefully as soon as possible.

Comment: @TheNumberOne that link points to the pastebin homepage, which doesn't contain any code.

Comment: While this question has an objective has now an objective winning criterion, I think it is too similar to [Weirdest obfuscated "Hello World!"](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22533/weirdest-obfuscated-hello-world) and [Produce an unexpected word](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28897).

Comment: But both of those are popularity contests with an accepted answer.

Comment: @ppperry Fixed link: http://ideone.com/qoEnFo

Comment: @Eridian, October 12 isn't a sunday.

Comment: Also, this popularity contest will give an unfair advantage to @molarmanful for simply having an earlier answer, thus giving people more time to upvote it.

Comment: @ppperry I could always get a handicap.

Comment: @molarmanful Yes. I have an answer to this in queue to be posted when the question reopens. In any case, this popularity contents has too short a runtime.

Comment: Date changed. I forgot to add 6 to today's date.

Comment: This is just begging for a [beatnik](http://esolangs.org/wiki/beatnik) answer, good question or not.

Comment: Heh. *date looks at code golf*

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE That certainly would be an inconvenience. I've never been in a relationship, so beginner's luck will prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript

I'll help you, even if the comment section is calling this challenge lame.

#### [Base64 Version](https://repl.it/BPpm)

```
atob("UmFjaGVsLCB3aWxsIHlvdSBnbyB0byBIb21lY29taW5nIHdpdGggbWU/")
```

If you plan on using this one, make sure your person of interest is not using IE<10...

---

#### [Not-the-Readable-Chars-You're-Looking-For Version](https://repl.it/BPpi)

```
unescape(escape("").replace(/uD./g,''))
```

This should be pretty obfuscated.

---

#### [7.2kB Version](https://jsfiddle.net/vpdbdx6r/)

```
v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0=[ function(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14){return '10d293a95915109e7675b011f404213902624f14427544885497d37034602b8583f0b7b5';}, function(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14){return vd57f593c9c5db784e6ceca5702b0e6d0.createElement(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14);}, function(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14){return v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14[0].getContext(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14[1]);}, function(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14){return v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14[0].text=v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14[1];}, function(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14){return null;}, function(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14){'ef2afd226e3384e34d9833fe09cd123db498754c3581ad5aabee934f80098b8fe5f668ad';}, function(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14){return 'cfd97391bd487ee1a2763054678f99f0b9bc94af87422c9f70db8400fef5759e6fbc1ae6';}, function(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14){v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14.style.display='none';return v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14;}, function(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14){v59512ffcd3230280f50421a3f69d5e8e.onload=v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14}, function(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14){v59512ffcd3230280f50421a3f69d5e8e.src=v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14;}, new Function("v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14","return unescape(decodeURIComponent(window.atob(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14)))"), function(v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14){vbe3ae157bcaf01bd49ec5a9b228e92fb=new Function('v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14',v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[10](v0a63761d20b234e464ed87e282c4eec3[v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14]));return vbe3ae157bcaf01bd49ec5a9b228e92fb;}]; v6d300e775e4eac08cfe35d5609d8d43b=[0,255,1]; v0a63761d20b234e464ed87e282c4eec3=[ 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ2NhbnZhcyclM0I=', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ25vbmUnJTNC', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJzJkJyUzQg==', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ3NjcmlwdCclM0I=', '', 'vc2ed17254c91fcd5e9da5a8cabddc384', 'v2a697c4e743f16832494c8b7c7a6d399', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ2RhdGElM0FpbWFnZSUyRnBuZyUzQmJhc2U2NCUyQyclM0I=', '', 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAJCAIAAABv85FHAAAApUlEQVQImQXBTSsDAAAG4MdrkuZkFyWT5OLiLvkb8j+d/YXtoMRNWg6maL7a9PI8a5dXV8qhfNR3DHnSsTw0RizkTV910i5rTxbtUjKsfX7rXs5iyBeP8Ze4iVVNONJVPafT+pRjcSozNmRH5slrbcZ5LQws2OSCuQ6a42SrZnHQQV94Z8R3smrXm1std5IT2Y9dea8xD+kPX7WdgWvFVCV3RYTiH9FPUBR7F+41AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwdmQ1N2Y1OTNjOWM1ZGI3ODRlNmNlY2E1NzAyYjBlNmQwLmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKHY4ZjJmMmI4NGI1OGNlY2UwNzQ3NTE5MWJjZDA1NmMxNCklM0I=', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwZG9jdW1lbnQ=', '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', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwbmV3JTIwSW1hZ2UoKSUzQg==', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwU3RyaW5nLmZyb21DaGFyQ29kZSh2OGYyZjJiODRiNThjZWNlMDc0NzUxOTFiY2QwNTZjMTQpJTNC']; vd57f593c9c5db784e6ceca5702b0e6d0=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](11)(); v82bdb1dbff37fafb81c17c858f505f30=new Function('v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14',v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[10](v0a63761d20b234e464ed87e282c4eec3[10])); v59512ffcd3230280f50421a3f69d5e8e=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[7](v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](13)()); v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[8](function(){ vb4feac7e380ce4027b10b115072774a1=v82bdb1dbff37fafb81c17c858f505f30(v0a63761d20b234e464ed87e282c4eec3[5]); v125a5958caabc04437b5651e3484e0c0=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[1](v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](0)()); v125a5958caabc04437b5651e3484e0c0.width=v59512ffcd3230280f50421a3f69d5e8e.width; v125a5958caabc04437b5651e3484e0c0.height=v59512ffcd3230280f50421a3f69d5e8e.height; v125a5958caabc04437b5651e3484e0c0.style.display=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](1)();v8c49168556c4200a9714748cf23ab460=v0a63761d20b234e464ed87e282c4eec3[4]; v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[2]([v125a5958caabc04437b5651e3484e0c0,v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](2)()]); v8ac110a75a55332c31b7b7492d726085=new Function('v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14',v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[10](v0a63761d20b234e464ed87e282c4eec3[14])); v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c.drawImage(v59512ffcd3230280f50421a3f69d5e8e, v6d300e775e4eac08cfe35d5609d8d43b[0], v6d300e775e4eac08cfe35d5609d8d43b[0]); vc497e192c67c30176b006f88371b130f=v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c.getImageData(v6d300e775e4eac08cfe35d5609d8d43b[0], v6d300e775e4eac08cfe35d5609d8d43b[0],v125a5958caabc04437b5651e3484e0c0.width,v125a5958caabc04437b5651e3484e0c0.height); v74fb68de63e9ca6d22063f5d0beae456=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](12)(); (new Function(v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[10](v8c49168556c4200a9714748cf23ab460)))(); vc2ed17254c91fcd5e9da5a8cabddc384=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c);v59512ffcd3230280f50421a3f69d5e8e=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](vc2ed17254c91fcd5e9da5a8cabddc384);v125a5958caabc04437b5651e3484e0c0=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v125a5958caabc04437b5651e3484e0c0);v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](vc497e192c67c30176b006f88371b130f);vc497e192c67c30176b006f88371b130f=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c);v5523471cb34c424dcb9ebd78b79be5aa=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c);v8c49168556c4200a9714748cf23ab460=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c);v75e840086f79b34c47902c12112a097b=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c);v9c9856fe170bc3577a0d0943f1f652a1=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c);vc2ed17254c91fcd5e9da5a8cabddc384=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c);v82a643d089e6f8b0d0d1f799065a1cc4=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c);vd57f593c9c5db784e6ceca5702b0e6d0=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c);v74fb68de63e9ca6d22063f5d0beae456=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c);v0a63761d20b234e464ed87e282c4eec3=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c);v6d300e775e4eac08cfe35d5609d8d43b=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c);v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c);v8f2f2b84b58cece07475191bcd056c14=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](vb4feac7e380ce4027b10b115072774a1);v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[4](v829471030a4228373270b4e31b5e3a5c); }); v74fb68de63e9ca6d22063f5d0beae456=v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[9](v9590e2cf04e941a01b43d16391df12b0[11](7)()+v0a63761d20b234e464ed87e282c4eec3[9]);
```

Done with the help of [this obfuscator](http://javascript2img.com/). Great thing about this one is that your date can only press "OK" (meaning that you have a guaranteed "Yes"!).

---

Good luck getting your date!

Comment: That's a nice touch on the third one. And it sure is obfuscated. Nice answer!